# delete a vector of pointers to abstract class

Tags: c++, memory, vector, std

I have the class Entity which is abstract. I use, in the game loop, an std::vector of pointers to Entity so that I can create objects of classes that extend Entity dynamically during the game.
I want to avoid memory leaks, so i want to release the memory taken by the vector.

is this enough?

```
GameLoop::~GameLoop() {
    int n = entities.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        entities.pop_back();
}
```

where entities is the

```
std::vector<Entity*> entities
```

Comment: Anything you `new`, you need to `delete`, but prefer automatic storage or smart pointers where possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, only you can figure out whether this is "enough". If these objects will still be referenced somewhere else, this won't work, obviously since this will leave dangling pointers behind. If these objects also own some other dynamically-scoped object, and their destructors does not delete them, this wouldn't be enough either. You need to fully understand how your entire application uses these objects, when they get constructed, and when they are no longer used anywhere, in order to determine whether the shown code is "enough".

Comment: You may want to use `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    entities.pop_back();
```

A shorter and faster way to do this is `entities.clear()`.

Assuming `entities` is a member, there is no need to even clear it: The object is about to be immediately destroyed, it's members will be destroyed, vector clears its elements automatically.

Note however that if the pointers in the vector own the pointed objects, then you do leak the memory because the pointer will cease to exist, and thus the previously owned objects can no longer be deleted.

In order for an owning pointer to release a dynamic allocation made by `new`, you must `delete` the pointer. You should not use owning bare poitners though  (unless for example if you're implementing a linked list that loops back onto itself). Use smart pointers and RAII containers instead.

P.S. The behaviour of deleting an object through a pointer to base is undefined unless the destructor of the base is virtual.